# May I use a template for a constant?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to write code as bellow:

```
template<typename T> const int a;

template<> const int a<float>=5;
template<> const int a<double>=14;
template<> const int a<char>=6;
template<> const int a<wchar>=33;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can, if your compiler supports the C++1y [variable templates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3651.pdf) feature.

```
template<typename T> const int a = 0;

template<> const int a<float> = 5;
template<> const int a<double> = 14;
template<> const int a<char> = 6;
template<> const int a<wchar_t> = 33;
```

I added spaces between the `>` and `=` of the specializations, because clang runs into a parsing error otherwise

> error: a space is required between a right angle bracket and an equals sign (use '> =')

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80a779fbff4606d7)

Comment: He doesn't want the type of the constant to vary with the type parameter.  `template<> const bool a<bool> = 17;` just doesn't work, while `template<> const int a<bool> = 17;` should.

Comment: But I need all those constants to be of the same type id est int. Is the above syntax achieving it ? I checked the code and the last two print as chars. So it isn't what I need. Is there a way to have the other behaviour ?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis I'd misunderstood what you were trying to do. Updated the answer.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis Don't rely on [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

Comment: @Praetorian It doesn't seem to work using gnu g++ . Do I have alternatives ?

Comment: @Jeffrey: He didn't say `typeid`.  He used "i.e.", except spelled it out.

Comment: Ahh, good ol' "maximal munch" rule, and it doesn't fall under the `>>` exception.  I wonder if this will be the next exception.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis Yeah, it doesn't look like gcc-4.9 has implemented this yet. Ben's answer is the only other solution that I know of.

Answer (score 5):

A solution for all versions of C++ (including before C++11):

```
template<typename T>
struct a { static const int value; };

template<> const int a<float>::value = 5;
template<> const int a<double>::value = 14;
template<> const int a<char>::value = 6;
template<> const int a<wchar_t>::value = 33;
```

(Note that the question used `wchar`, which is not a standard type)

It's a little clumsier, but works.

Comment: I knew that solution, but I would like better the other one you posted before. So it seems that only macros will solve the problem ?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: Go ahead and accept Praetorian's answer, now that he fixed it.  (As far as I can tell, it's exactly the code in your question, plus a default value)

Comment: `constexpr` functions could work too, with a bit less line noise at the call site (just `()` instead of `::value`)